# Browser bookmarks location variable

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, browser, bookmarks

I'm wondering if there is a variable in Firefox, Internet Explorer and Google Chrome, etc which contains the location of the bookmarks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For IE you want to call [SHGetKnownFolderPath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762188%28VS.85%29.aspx) with [FOLDERID_Favorites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378457%28VS.85%29.aspx).

For Mozilla you can use the [Directory Service](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/File_I//O#Getting_special_files) and ask for ["Favs"](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/xpcom/io/nsDirectoryServiceDefs.h).  This may vary depending on your OS.  See the linked header file for details.

For Chrome, see [this](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=501d9a38a1976525&hl=en).

Comment: The Chrome link are no longer valid.